How to show that the induced representation of the trivial representation is reducible
"Let G be a finite group and let H be a proper subgroup of G. Let 1 be the trivial 1-dimensional representation of H. Prove that Ind$^{G}_H$1 (the induced representation) is never irreducible."
How can i show this? I think one way to do it is showing that the induced representation of the trivial representation is the permutation representation of its cosets and since a permutation representation is reducible, the induced rep. is reducible to. But how can I show these two steps? Moreover, is there another way to show this? Maybe using Frobenius reciprocity? Thanks in advance.

Please don't use pictures for text.

OK, i will change it.

What does Frobenius tell you about $\dim \text{Hom}(\text{Ind}_H^G 1, 1)$?

Let $\mathbb{1}: H\to \mathbb{F}^{\times}$ be a trivial representation. Recall that
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{G} (\mathbb{1}) = \{f:G\to \mathbb{F}\mid \forall h\in H,\forall g\in G: f(hg) = f(g)\}\\
\forall x, g\in G: gf(x) = f(xg)
\end{equation}
Note that the identity function $f_{0}(g)\equiv 1$ is in $\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\mathbb{1})$. Moreover $f_{0}$ is a $G$-invariant vector, since for any $x$ and $g$ in $G$ we have $gf_{0}(x) = f_{0}(xg) \equiv 1$.  Note that $\mathbb{F}f_{0}$ is then a subrepresentation of $\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\mathbb{1})$. Since $H$ is a proper subgroup $\dim(\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\mathbb{1})) = [G:H]\ne 1$, thus $\mathbb{F}f_{0}$ is a proper subrepresentation. This proves that $\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\mathbb{1})$ is reducible.

Consider the induced character $(1_H)^G$. By Frobenius reciprocity it follows $[(1_H)^G,1_G]=[1_H,1_H]=1$. Thus $1_G$ is an irreducible constituent of $(1_H)^G$ with multiplicity $1$, and since $(1_H)^G(1)=|G:H|>1=1_G(1)$ then necessarily $(1_H)^G$ has at least one nontrivial irreducible constituent. Therefore $(1_H)^G$ is not irreducible.

The underlying vector space of $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G 1$ is the set of all functions from $G$ to $\mathbb C$, where $G$ acts by right translation.  This is clearly a $|G|$-dimensional representation of $G$ which contains the $1$-dimensional subrepresentation of constant functions, so it is not irreducible.
